# WHY AM I connection status 0 in GetExtendedTcpTable

Tags: delphi

I want to view the IPV6 connections for TCP and UDP protocols via GetExtendedTcpTable in Delphi 7. I have written the code to display the connection information . The problem is that I am getting connection status as "0" . As far as i have read , the valid states are 1-12. Here is my code below , could someone point out the mistake .

```
const
  ANY_SIZE    = 1;

type
  PTMib_TCP6Row = ^TMib_TCP6Row;
  TMib_TCP6Row = packed record
    dwState         : DWORD ;
    LocalAddr       : IN6_ADDR    ;
    dwLocalScopeId  : DWORD       ;
    dwLocalPort     : DWORD       ;
    RemoteAddr      : IN6_ADDR    ;
    dwRemoteScopeId : DWORD       ;
    dwRemotePort    : DWORD       ;
    dwProcessId     : DWORD       ;
  end;

  PTMIB_TCP6TABLE = ^TMIB_TCP6TABLE;
  TMIB_TCP6TABLE = packed record
    dwNumEntries : DWORD;
    Table: array[0..ANY_SIZE - 1] of TMib_TCP6Row;
  end;

function GetTCPEntries: Boolean;
var
  tcpTable1: PTMIB_TCP6TABLE;
  dwSize1, dwSize2, dwSize3, I: DWORD;             
begin
  Result := False;
  dwSize1 := 0;
  dwSize2 := 0;
  dwSize3 := 0;
  if GetExtendedTcpTable(nil, @dwSize1, False, AF_INET6, TCP_TABLE_OWNER_PID_ALL, 0) = ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER then
  begin
    GetMem(tcpTable1, dwSize1);
    GetExtendedTcpTable(tcpTable1, @dwSize1, False, AF_INET6, TCP_TABLE_OWNER_PID_ALL, 0);
    dwSize2 := tcpTable1^.dwNumEntries;
    for i := 0 to dwSize2-1 do
    begin            
      //Form1.UpdateLog('State of connection = ' + IntTostr(tcpTable1.Table[i].dwState)  + #13#10);
    end;
    FreeMem(tcpTable1, dwSize1);
  end;
end;
```

dwState is 0 in my case.

I have seen the output of the sysinternals program "TCPView.exe" which shows connection state as "Listening" so there is nothing wrong with my machine.

Help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Comment: @DavidHeffernan : We already have used these definitions successfully for IPV4. I just copied them here.No, the c++ header file does not use packed records. As for the function return part, it is just a demo code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the documentation, it would seem that the struct that is returned when you pass `AF_INET6` and `TCP_TABLE_OWNER_PID_ALL` is [`MIB_TCP6ROW_OWNER_PID`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa366896.aspx).

But that struct looks nothing like your declaration of `TMib_TCP6Row`. And that's why the values that you read out of your `TMib_TCP6Row` records are not what you expect.

Read the documentation for [`GetExtendedTcpTable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa365928.aspx). In the `AF_INET6` table it lists [`MIB_TCP6TABLE_OWNER_PID`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa366905.aspx) as the struct associated with `TCP_TABLE_OWNER_PID_ALL`. And `MIB_TCP6TABLE_OWNER_PID` has an array of `MIB_TCP6ROW_OWNER_PID`.

The bottom line is that the record that you are using on your side of the interface does not match the struct used on the other side.

---

Some other comments:

- It is incorrect to pack these records. The C++ header file does not do so and uses aligned structs. Aligned structs is the norm. It's usually a safe bet when interacting with the Windows API that structs will be aligned.
- You are also neglecting to check the return value of `GetExtendedTcpTable` in the second call that you make.

Comment: thanks . it works now. the status comes as listening mode now